# How to make edges appear above nodes in React Flow?

Tags: reactjs, react-flow

I am using React Flow v9 and I want to make the edges appear above the nodes. I have tried setting the z-index for the node to 0 or the z-index for the edge to 100 but they don't seem to work. It always falls back to nodes having a z-index of 3 and edges having a z-index of 2.

Is there a way to get this behavior?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

for future record, I found that applying

```
.react-flow__node {
   z-index: -1 !important;
}
```

will override the default `z-index: 1000` and `-1` will be displayed below all `z-index: auto` which is the default.

class name from https://reactflow.dev/docs/guides/theming/#react-flow-class-names